# How to implement if and else statements? when writing a language compiler

Tags: c#, interpreter

I am using this example project written by Joel Pobar. I got this from:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc136756.aspx

Okay so to implement a simple Print command I need to:

First declare the class in the **Ast.cs**:

```
// print <expr>
public class Print : Stmt
{
    public Expr Expr;
}
```

Secondly I implemented the method into **Parser.cs**:

```
 // <stmt> := print <expr> 

        // <expr> := <string>
        // | <int>
        // | <arith_expr>
        // | <ident>
        if (this.tokens[this.index].Equals("Printl"))
        {
            this.index++;
            Print print = new Print();
            print.Expr = this.ParseExpr();
            result = print;
        }
```

Lastly I implemented a check in the **CodeGen.cs**:

```
  else if (stmt is Print)
    {
        // the "print" statement is an alias for System.Console.WriteLine. 
        // it uses the string case
        this.GenExpr(((Print)stmt).Expr, typeof(string));
        this.il.Emit(Emit.OpCodes.Call, typeof(System.Console).GetMethod("WriteLine", new System.Type[] { typeof(string) }));
    }
```

Now this allows me to create an interpreter and compiles a file if it matches the syntax. This interpreter supports variables, loops, and basic printing text and variable values. However I am a bit confused on how to implement if and else statements.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: You say you have loops working?  `if-else` is very much like a loop control expression.

Answer (score 1):

MSIL has conditional branch instructions.  You'll have to arrange for the result of the conditional expression to be on top of the value stack, and then [use a conditional branch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ahkzc1bh.aspx) to jump to the else-stuff (skipping the then-stuff) or not.  The end of the then-stuff will unconditionally branch over the else-stuff.

Of course, you'll need to define and mark labels for the beginning and end of the else-stuff.  The above link covers label creation.

Here are the conditional branch instructions, found in [the OpCodes class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Beq Field
Beq_S Field
Bge Field
Bge_S Field
Bge_Un Field
Bge_Un_S Field
Bgt Field
Bgt_S Field
Bgt_Un Field
Bgt_Un_S Field
Ble Field
Ble_S Field
Ble_Un Field
Ble_Un_S Field
Blt Field
Blt_S Field
Blt_Un Field
Blt_Un_S Field
Bne_Un Field
Bne_Un_S Field 
Brfalse Field
Brfalse_S Field
Brtrue Field
Brtrue_S Field 
Switch Field
```

Note that many of these combine a comparison witha conditional branch.  For example,

> The `ble` instruction transfers control to the specified target instruction if *value1* is less than or equal to *value2*. The effect is identical to performing a `cgt` instruction (`cgt.un` for floats) followed by a `brfalse` branch to the specific target instruction.

[The documentation for `ILGenerator.DefineLabel()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.ilgenerator.definelabel.aspx) has a complete example of a conditional, implementing:

```
IF A < 100 AND B < 100
    RETURN A + B
ELSE
    RETURN -1
```

Comment: Do you think you can share some code for implementing 'if' and 'else' statements?

Comment: @user2874682: I just added a link to the `DefineLabel()` docs, which have exactly such a sample.

Comment: The ILGenerator.DefineLabel() documentation is confusing me. I don't know what code should be put into which file/class